# Facebook JS and PHP SDK Integration

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that I’m attempting to implement a Facebook login to.  Users will login using there Facebook credentials and will be able to post to their Facebook timeline.  The login process will take place via the Javascript SDK but posting/publishing to their timeline will take place via the PHP SDK as there will be some additional database stuff happening as well on the server side.

Javascript login is working fine but the single use access token causes problems when I make multiple Ajax calls to the server.  I get a “This authorization code has been used.” error on the server side.  I’ve followed the instructions to create a long-lived token using the Facebook developer page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension and I have confirmed each client receives its own token, etc.

I am using  getJavaScriptHelper() on the server to determine if the user is logged in (still logged in) before performing any further processing but cannot figure out ***how to update the short-lived access token on the client with the long-lived one***.  I could use the server-side long-lived token by putting it into a session which I’ve seen suggested but then unless I’m missing something it seems I still have to figure out whether the user is still logged in, manage the session variable, storing and updating that token and tearing down the session when the user logs out which I thought the Facebook SDK’s would do for me.

*Additional information or clarification of issue.*

I could just use the JS SDK but it would potential make my code more complex and anyway I’m simply trying to follow the Facebook documentation which I thought made sense but now seems incomplete, or I’m missing something.

Here are what I believe to be the key bits of code, forgetting about the long-lived token for now: -

The Javascript login code pretty much straight out of the Facebook documentation.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : app_id,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8'
});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
        } else {
            FB.login();
        }
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The PHP part and why I’m trying to get a long-lived access token.  After login the first Ajax call works fine passing through the code below and allowing me to publish some text to the Facebook user’s timeline.  The second Ajax call fails at getAccessToken() with “This authorization code has been used” unless I manually reload the browser page.  ***How do I get around this or what am I doing wrong?***

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    error_log ( 'getAccessToken() - Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    error_log ( 'getAccessToken() - Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    exit;
}

// Further code to publish to users timeline…
```

Comment: why would you need a long lived token? why not just store the default one in the session? that being said, why not just use the js sdk only and forget about the php sdk?

Comment: _“This authorization code has been used”_ is the message you get if you try to exchange the `code` parameter for an access token a second time.